# C++ std::hash_map: What is the key's role

Tags: c++, hashmap, key, std

Both `maps` and `hash_maps` are designed so hold `pairs` of `<key, data>`. It's clear to me why the map should have a key for it's sorting (more precisely: treeing), but I don't understand why hash_maps need a key, why can't it's data alone be hashed and placed into the hash table?

I couldn't find the answer neither in the documentation nor by searching around the net.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table didn't answer your question?

Comment: So in a map why couldn't the data alone be used for sorting (or treeing)? In both cases the concept being modeled is that of a dictionary, that's why you split into a key and associated data, because it's a useful idea, not for any implementation reasons. If you don't have need for a key then you are modeling a set, and you would use a std::set or a set::unordered_set.

Comment: A map doesn't hold a key for treeing. A map holds a key because it is a map. It maps keys to values. The treeing is to do with the  implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unordered_set` works precisely in the way you describe. However, there are times when you want to map from one piece of data to another; that's where `std::unordered_map` comes into play.

Answer (score 4):

Walk to the cupboard. Get the phone book out and look up a number. It has a mapping between a name and number

Comment: Like :) But the accepted answer is already take by Alex as he preceded.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_data_structure), where a key is also data.

C++ offers some different flavour of them: [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), etc...

Answer (score 0):

Hash Map which is also called `Unordered Map` uses a `HASH` of the `KEY` as an `index` of buckets or Slots.In other word, any Hash Table needs a hash function to compute an `index` into an array of buckets or slots, from which the correct value can be found.These `index` are the Key of the Hash Table, which are used for accessing the data in O(1) time in best case.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong, the key, which is part of the structure of the hash_map's pair type, and the hash, which is the result of the hash function, are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the data itself as the key, the appropriate container is `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. A map holds both a key and a value; the difference between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` is in **how** the data is organized; `std::map` sorts by the key, and `std::unordered_map` hashes by the key.